# Creating a flat spectrum filterbank

Tags: filters, audio

I'm trying to create a filterbank whose frequency response is generally flat when summed in parallel. Are there any tips to choosing center frequencies and bandwidths for a filterbank of overlapping bandpass filters? Does a gammatone filterbank sum up to a flat response?

Comment: Can you give a little more details regarding your application?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac, you got it in your first comment: I need to modify the signal. I want to take a block of audio samples, run it through a filterbank, analyse each filter, and depending on the analysis, sum up some bands of the filterbank while ignoring others. I want to repeat this throughout an audio file block-wise without artifacts when I reconstruct by summing the filters I choose.

Comment: In that case I would suggest using a bank of "zero phase" filters, i.e. phase aligned linear phase filters. That simplifies everything tremendously and guarantees that your results are what you expect them to be. The individual filters' frequency responses can be chosen so that they overlap only with the two adjacent bands and sum to one there. So overlapping triangle or cosine segment responses would be commonly used.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac thanks for getting back to me. So in this case the algorithm is: read a file, read block -> window -> filterbank -> choose bands -> sum bands -> write block (add previous) slide by overlap -> repeat? Can you point me towards a good programming-geared resource on the implementation of block-based processing?

Comment: In particular I'm stuck on some of the 'bookkeeping' operations of overlap-add, namely, how many buffers do I need to store at any given time, when can I output, when do I add, when do I zero pad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist [perfect reconstruction filter banks](http://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Perfect_Reconstruction_Filter_Banks.html) that do what you suggest.

[image]

One example of the choice of $H_i(z)$ for $i= 0 \ldots N-1$ is the FFT filters (followed by the IFFT filters $F_i(z)$).

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the frequency response of the i-th channel is something like the Z-transform of H_i(z)? In the non-resampling case, this looks like a bank of comb filters, a parallel ensemble of simple one-element delay lines.

Comment: While technically correct, it should be mentioned that the perfect reconstruction property relies on aliasing in the downsampled bands just cancelling the right way. This makes any modification of the filter bands critical, as the aliases stop cancelling and you get reconstruction artefacts well beyond simple response ripples. So if the OP is planning to use the filter bank to modify the input, this is usually not the right option.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac:So you're saying that FFT modification is not a good way to do filtering?!?? ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyParks: Yes, you are correct. Though there are many other ways to choose the H / F.  And, as Jazzmaniac says, there may be better ways to attack your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few common approaches

1. Filters sum to 1

$$\sum_i H_i(\omega) = 1$$

where $H_i(\omega)$ is the feq. response of the $i$-th filter. For a signal $f(x)$ reconstruction is just adding up the spatial responses

$$f(x) = \sum_i (f \ast h_i)(x) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longleftrightarrow} \sum_i F(\omega)H_i(\omega) = F(\omega)$$

2. Square of filters sum to 1

$$\sum_i |H_i(\omega)|^2 = 1$$

These filters now form a tight wavelet frame. Basically you apply the wavelet transform (filtering via cross-correlation) once to get the wavelet coefficients (filter responses) then apply the reverse of the transform (filtering) to get back the original signal. Something like

$$f_i(x) = (f \star h_i)(x) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longleftrightarrow} F(\omega)H^*(\omega)$$

$$f(x) = \sum_i (f_i \ast h_i)(x) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longleftrightarrow} \sum_i F(\omega)H^*(\omega)H(\omega) = F(\omega)$$

3. Two different filters

Same as above except different filters for each transform forwards and backwards. The filters obey

$$\sum_i H^*_i(\omega)G_i(\omega) = 1$$

Then reconstruction is

$$f_i(x) = (f \star h_i)(x) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longleftrightarrow} F(\omega)H^*(\omega)$$

$$f(x) = \sum_i (f_i \ast g_i)(x) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\longleftrightarrow} \sum_i F(\omega)H^*(\omega)G(\omega) = F(\omega)$$

Comment: I don't see how 2) requires the basis to have affine symmetry, i.e. the basis vectors need to be wavelets. Any basis with the magnitude squared sum property will do.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Yea that meaning was my intention, I'm not sure what affine symmetry is :$ (was it because i used the word adjoint? have removed it)

Comment: I'm assuming this is mathematically correct but it doesn't really help me create a filterbank that is flat.

Comment: @AnthonyParks have a look at wavelets. Wavelet denoising uses a similar pipeline to what you desire.